# What does this C code do?

Tags: c

I need to know the output of the following c function

```
bool GC_search_memaddr (void* high_add, void* low_add, void* search_add)
{
    void ** gc_ptr_to_ptr;
    void * gc_temp;
    gc_temp = high_add;
    while( gc_temp > low_add )
    { 
        gc_temp = gc_temp - 1;
        gc_ptr_to_ptr = (void**)gc_temp;
        if ((*gc_ptr_to_ptr) == search_add)
            return True;
    }
    return False;
}
```

In this all 3 of the input functions are pointers. I thought that this was just a simple increment based search function but the problem is that if you change all of them to int the output of the function changes sometimes.
Can anybody tell what exactly is happening here ...

Comment: it looks like a very weird way of telling if `search_add` is between `high_add` and `low_add`? I have no idea... what is the function used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `low_add` and `high_add` contain the start and end addresses of a region of memory. The function searches that region of memory for a pointer that contains the same value that's in `search_add`. From the function name I'm assuming it's part of some garbage collector.

Comment: Correct.  Though does arithmetic on `void *`, which is non-standard; and it also won't work on architectures that have alignment requirements for loading `void *` values.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithmetic is likely your problem.  The line:

```
gc_temp = gc_temp - 1;
```

is going to change the value of `gc_temp` by whatever your compiler decides `sizeof(void)` is.  If you change the parameters and local variables to `int`, they will iterate by exactly `1`.  Break out your debugger and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

As `blastfurnace` says, it's searching byte-by-byte for a supplied pointer value.  The `int` equivalent would be:

```
bool GC_search_memaddr (void* high_add, void* low_add, int search_add)
{
    int * gc_ptr_to_int;
    void * gc_temp;
    gc_temp = high_add;
    while( gc_temp > low_add )
    { 
        gc_temp = gc_temp - 1;
        gc_ptr_to_int = (int *)gc_temp;
        if ((*gc_ptr_to_int) == search_add)
            return True;
    }
    return False;
}
```

Though, `gc_temp` should actually be of type `char *`, and it should be using `memcpy()` to account for endianness issues, so it should really look like:

```
bool GC_search_memaddr (void* high_add, void* low_add, void *search_add)
{
    void *gc_ptr;
    char *gc_temp = high_add;

    while (gc_temp > low_add)
    { 
        gc_temp--;
        memcpy(&gc_ptr, gc_temp, sizeof gc_ptr);
        if (gc_ptr == search_add)
            return True;
    }
    return False;
}
```

Comment: I like how your corrected version avoids alignment issues and doesn't assume that ints and pointers are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The function seems to determine if the address search_add is between the addresses high_add and low_add. Why this isn't done with pointer subtraction and why there is the ugly cast to `void**` just to dereference it on the next possible occasion is beyond me.